# gThumb crashes immediately on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, gthumb

I used gThumb for several years on 16.04.  I installed it on my new 20.04 system but it crashes immediately when started.

I have one HDMI monitor and one DisplayPort monitor and a GeForce GTX 1660 graphics card.

The log file shows what looks like an Nvidia issue but I don't know enough to start troubleshooting it.

Log file:

```
6:45:49 PM gthumb: gthumb: ../../../../src/cairo-surface.c:930: cairo_surface_reference: Assertion `CAIRO_REFERENCE_COUNT_HAS_REFERENCE (&surface->ref_count)' failed.  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VS278 (DFP-2): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VS278 (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VS278 (DFP-2): connected  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VS278 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VS278 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VS278 (DFP-1): connected  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS  
6:45:48 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
```

Here is a screenshot from the Gnome crash report:

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same problem with gThumb on Ubuntu Budgie: gthumb: ../../../../src/cairo-surface.c:930: cairo_surface_reference: Assertion `CAIRO_REFERENCE_COUNT_HAS_REFERENCE (&surface->ref_count)' failed.
Aborted

At least I could break down the issue to 4 images in my image library (all of them panorama/360° images) were causing the crash. After moving the images to a backup folder gThumb worked again.

I will try to open a bug report, when I find out to which project to report this issue to.

At least it should not crash just because one or a few images are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting this bug for quite some time, got the same cairo error message.

Today I found out that I CAN open pictures from the desktop (that I put there for testing) but CANNOT open them from another location, a cloud synced location, unless....

I pause my cloud drive, open a file and unpause the cloud drive.

I use stack cloud services run with an appimage. I also have an installed version of the sync software which is not in use.

This was the very first time that I could use gthumb again after taking some kind of action, no clue on how/why.

I will report back.

Edit:
**Cloud drive was a fluke, had nothing to do with it!**
When I started systematically moving images between two folders I was able to find two corrupt jpg files, both rather large.

As soon as they were gone, gthumb worked again.

I missed being able to use gthumb so much!